# Prove or disprove the positivity of the ess inf of a singular function

Tags: measure-theory, integration, singularity-theory, counterexamples

Consider a measurable **radial** function $u:\Bbb R^d\to(0,\infty)$ such that
$$\int_{B_\delta(0)} u(x) d x=\infty\quad\forall\,\, \delta>0.$$

I would like to prove or to disprove that there exists $r>0$ such that
$\DeclareMathOperator*\essinf{ess inf}$
$$\essinf_{x\in B_r(0)} u(x)>0.$$

That is there exists a constant $r>0$ and $c>0$ such that
$$u(x)\geq c\quad \text{for almost every $x\in B_r(0)$}$$

Note that the radially is very important here. Indeed if $u$ is not radial it is easy to disprove this by considering $u(x)=\lvert x\rvert^\gamma\mathbb{1}_{V}(x)$, $\gamma<-d$ where $V$ is any double cone with apex at the origin. In this case we have

$$ \essinf_{B_\delta(0)} u=0\quad\text{and}\quad \int_{B_\delta(0)} u(x) d x=\infty\quad\forall\,\, \delta>0.$$

Comment: TeX note: you can define new "operators with limits" using `\DeclareMathOperator*\essinf{essinf}`$\DeclareMathOperator*\essinf{essinf}$. Then compare $\displaystyle\essinf_{B_\delta(0)} u$ `\displaystyle\essinf_{B_\delta(0)} u` to $\displaystyle ess\inf_{B_\delta(0)} u$ `\displaystyle ess\inf_{B_\delta(0)} u`. I have edited accordingly. In the process, I also changed the request to prove the *existence* of the ess.inf. to a request to prove the *positivity* of the ess.inf., which seemed to be what you meant; I hope this was all right.

Comment: @tj_, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418318/prove-or-disprove-the-positivity-of-the-ess-inf-of-a-singular-function#comment1073912_418318), various preferences can be accommodated; for example $\DeclareMathOperator*\essinf{ess inf}\displaystyle\essinf_{B_\delta(0)} u$ `\DeclareMathOperator*\essinf{ess inf}\displaystyle\essinf_{B_\delta(0)} u` also works just fine.  But $\displaystyle ess\inf_{B_\delta(0)} u$ should not be used.

Comment: I don't think this is research level ... for each $n$ let $u$ be continuous on $\frac{1}{n+1}<|x|<\frac{1}{n}$, going to zero at the lower limit and $\infty$ at the upper limit, growing fast enough that its integral over this region is infinite.